# Podio Android SDK item create API call error "Object not found"

Tags: android, podio

I have a problem with the Podio SDK on Android in the following scenario:

I have uploaded an image to Podio from our server in a php script and returned the file_id to my Android app via http. The id seems to be valid, but when i try to create an item using this file_id for an image field value i get the following error messages:

```
E/Volley: [49051] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for https://api.podio.com/item/app/17418679

com.podio.sdk.ApiError: {"error_parameters":{},"error_detail":null,"error_propagate":false,"request":{"url":"http:\/\/api.podio.com\/item\/app\/17418679","query_string":"","method":"POST"},"error_description":"Object not found","error":"not_found"}
```

If i do not attach the image the item create call works fine
I used the newest version of the Podio Android SDK from Github (https://github.com/podio/podio-android) compiled using Android Studio 2.3 and build tools version 25.

I already found an error where the wrong app_id was used, but fixing that still left me with the same message.

This used to work only a few weeks ago, maybe there was change in the API? Do you have any tips on what else could cause this problem? I am using different client id / secret in the php script than in the app, could that be the reason?

Comment: The contents of the response do look a little strange. In theory it should be possible to determine if it's an API issue or a client issue by intercepting the data sent by the client. If you could do that and share the data here, I think it would help the developers track down the problem.